# Bathroom fixture help

Tags: electrical, wiring

I am working on installing a new light fixture in the bathroom and the wiring has 4 black wires and 4 white wires. Not used to seeing this and don’t know how to proceed. The House was built in the 70s if that helps.

[image]

Currently there are 3 black wires all connected together, 4 white wires not connected to anything, and 1 black wire not connected.

The three black wires were all connected by the previous owners, so I have not done anything to change that.

Light fixture has a black, white, and a ground like all other fixtures I have installed.

The fixture is is powered on by a double wall switch. One switch controls two lights at once, and the other controls the fixture I am working to install.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: I don't suppose you took a picture before you disconnected everything.

Comment: Do you have a photo of the inside of the switch box?

Comment: one of theose white wires has black paint. that's important.

Comment: Agree with Jack here , you probably have a hot neutral cable supply in the box and a switch loop down to the switch and a switched outlet or a hot feed to an outlet. All of these options could be code compliant but we can’t even guess without more information. + for jack because so many DIY problems can be solved with a picture before taking things apart.

Comment: One of the white wires is hot. I have marked that one with some black sharpie. Agree: in hindsight I should have taken a picture. Won’t make that mistake again